# To implement an interface, use Java Application or Java Class Library?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I am new to java and sqlite, but I've been asked by my Tutor to make a project connecting Sqlite in Java. But i really couldn't understand what does he really want??

this what he asked for:

"***Create a Java Class (DBAccesslmpl) that provides access to data in SQLite database, an interface for this class (DBAccess) will be provided***."

so is he asking to make Java Application OR Java Class Library

Comment: he is asking you to write a class that will be a concrete implementation of an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 'tutor' will provide you an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)  **DBAccess** and you will have to code the implementation **DBAccessImpl**  of that interface. So basically you have only one class to code.

The interface is the contract that your class will have to respect.

Comment: yeah i understand that but what i cant understand that what type of project am i using. It might look silly to ask this Questions but i really have no idea.

thanks for replying

Comment: Long time since I used netbeans, but Java Class Library project seems enough.

Comment: fair enough this is the answer i couldn't get from him.
Thank you very much for your help